# An integral involving beta function

Tags: definite-integrals, beta-function

For $-1 \leq \theta \leq 1$ and $\nu > -1/2$, prove that the function 
$$
f(x; \theta,\nu) = \frac{(1-x^2)^{\nu -1/2}} {(1-2\theta x +\theta^2)^\nu B(\nu+1/2,1/2)}
$$
is a valid probability density function for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$. Here $B(.,.)$ denotes the Beta function.

My attempt: I substituted $x=\sin(\alpha)$ in the integral and it reduced to
$$
I= \frac{1}{B(\nu+1/2,1/2)}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos(\alpha)^{2 \nu}}{(1-2 \theta \sin(\alpha)+\theta^2)^\nu} d \alpha.
$$
But how do I simplify the above integral to a Beta function? Notice that the integral turns out to be independent of $\theta$.

Comment: "Notice that the integral turns out to be independent of $\theta$" - why did you make that conclusion?

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Yeah, it's a mistake. I'll edit it. Assuming that the integral is one, I concluded that the integral is independent of $\theta$.

Comment: A bit of care is needed: if $x = \theta = 1$ and $\nu > 0$ then $f$ is not defined.

Comment: When someone says "integral involving the F function" I expect the F function actually be inside the integral. It's a little confusing

Comment: @You'reInMyEye: Correct. My integral results in Beta function rather the function being an integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of everything unnecessary, we need to evaluate the following integral:

$$I( \nu, \theta) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-x^2)^{\nu -1/2}} {(1-2\theta x +\theta^2)^\nu }dx$$

We use the substitution:

$$x=-\cos \alpha$$

$$I( \nu, \theta) = \int_{0}^\pi \frac{\sin^{2\nu} \alpha} {(1+2\theta \cos \alpha +\theta^2)^\nu }d \alpha$$

There is a theorem, saying:

> $$\int_{0}^\pi g \left( \frac{\sin^{2} \alpha} {1+2\theta \cos \alpha +\theta^2 } \right)d \alpha= \begin{cases} \int_{0}^\pi g \left( \sin^{2} \alpha \right)d \alpha, \quad \theta^2 < 1 \\ \int_{0}^\pi g \left( \frac{\sin^{2} \alpha}{\theta^2} \right)d \alpha, \quad \theta^2 \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

See for example Gradstein-Ryzhik 3.036. (the old edition I have has it wrong though, the values of $\theta$ are confused).

You have the first case. Thus:

$$I( \nu, \theta) = \int_{0}^\pi \sin^{2\nu} \alpha ~d \alpha=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} ~\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\nu+1 \right)}=B \left( \frac{1}{2},\nu+\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

Use the definition of the Beta function and the properties of the Gamma function to prove this.

See here for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: What's the proof of the theorem? All I could find is the result in the Gradstein-Ryzhik book.

Comment: @pikachuchameleon, I don't know, unfortunately

Comment: G & R never tells you how they did't. On the other hand, it's quite difficult to find the reference they gave:
\begin{align}
&\mbox{LA Laska, W., Sammlung von Formeln der reinen und angewandten Mathematik,}
\\&\mbox{Friedrich Viewig
und Sohn, Braunschweig, 1888–1894.}
\end{align}

Comment: Google Translation: Laska, W., collection of formulas of pure and applied
Mathematics, Friedrich Viewig
and son, Braunschweig, 1888-1894.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Sammlung-Formeln-Reinen-Angewandten-Mathematik/dp/B004C1OQN0/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1470179264&sr=1-5

Answer (score 4):

Playing with the integral, I found a solution which also proves **@You're In My Eye**'s formula.

First, we define $\phi : [-\pi/2, \pi/2] \to \Bbb{R}$ by

$$\phi(t) = \frac{\cos^2 t}{1 - 2\theta \sin t + \theta^2}.$$

It is easy to check that $\phi$ has a unique maximum at $t_{\max} = \arcsin \theta$ with $\phi(t_{\max}) = 1$.  Thus we can uniquely define two functions $t_{\pm} : [0, 1] \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfying the following conditions

$$ -\frac{\pi}{2} \leq t_{-}(y) \leq t_{+}(y) \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \phi(t_{\pm}(y)) = y, \qquad \forall y \in [0, 1]. $$

$\hspace{8em}$ [image]

In fact, we can find a simple formula for $t_{\pm}$. To this end, let $s_{\pm} = \sin(t_{\pm})$. Then they solve

$$ 1 - s_{\pm}^2 = y(1 - 2\theta s_{\pm} + \theta^2) \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad s_{\pm} = \theta y \pm \sqrt{\smash[b]{(1 - y)(1 - \theta^2 y)}}. $$

Now here comes the trickiest part: the above expression for $s_{\pm}$ can be written as follows:

$$ s_{\pm} = \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - (1-y)}} \cdot \theta \sqrt{\smash[b]{\vphantom{1}y}} \pm \sqrt{\smash[b]{1-y}} \sqrt{\smash[b]{1 - \theta^2 y}}. $$

Thus taking arcsine to both side and taking advantage of the sine addition formula, we have

$$ t_{\pm} = \arcsin(s_{\pm}) = \arcsin(\theta\sqrt{u}) \pm \arcsin\sqrt{1-y}. $$

Now we are almost done. For any nice function $g$ on $[0, 1]$, we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} g(\phi(t)) \, dt
&= \int_{0}^{1} g(y) \, d (t_{+}(y) - t_{-}(y)) \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} g(y) \, d (2\arcsin\sqrt{1-y}) \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} g(\cos^2 \alpha) \, d\alpha,
\end{align*}

where the last line follow from the substitution $\alpha = \arcsin\sqrt{1-y}$. This is now equivalent to **@You're In My Eye**'s formula and the computation is done.

Comment: Thank you, Sangchul Lee! This is very interesting. By the way, I forgot to say that $g$ should be a nice function, which is specified in G-R.

Comment: @You'reInMyEye, It was very interesting also to me! I have never thought such a nice formula would be true. Thank you for introducing me that. :)